# Where can I find the text of the DACA action?

Tags: united-states, immigration, barack-obama, illegal-immigration

I am looking for a PDF or website that has the actual text of the [DACA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Action_for_Childhood_Arrivals) (Deferred Action for Childhood Arrivals) order that President Obama issued in 2012.  Is there a PDF out there for it?

Answer (score 4):

DACA was not legislation or an executive order; it technically comes from a [memo issued by then Secretary of Homeland Security Janet Napolitano](https://www.dhs.gov/xlibrary/assets/s1-exercising-prosecutorial-discretion-individuals-who-came-to-us-as-children.pdf) on June 15th 2012. It is not called DACA in the memo though (which is why it's not as easy to google for).

Some select quotes (that form the basis of DACA):

> how ... [DHS] should enforce the Nation's immigration laws against
>   certain young people who were brought to this country as children
>
> ...
>
> • came to the United States under the age of sixteen;
>
> • has continuously resided in the United States for a least five years
>   preceding the date of this memorandum and is present in the United
>   States on the date ofthis memorandum;
>
> • is currently in school, has
>   graduated from high school, has obtained a general education
>   development certificate, or is an honorably discharged veteran of the
>   Coast Guard or Armed Forces ofthe United States;
>
> • has not been convicted of a felony offense, a significant misdemeanor offense, multiple
>   misdemeanor offenses, or otherwise poses a threat to national security or public safety;
>   and
>
> • is not above the age of thirty.